# What happens to the other planes when the Material Plane get destroyed or disappears?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, planes

I have read up about Planes, about the Great Beyond, basically the whole of http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/the-planes and http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Inner_Sphere

I was wondering how to handle if a Material Plane gets destroyed or it disappears. A friend of mine and I both have different perspective on this. I think that nothing happens except for the link to the Material Plane disappears. My friend thinks that if the Material Plane get destroyed, the whole Inner Sphere gets destroyed.

I do know that we can get creative when it comes to our own interpretation, but I was wondering about Pathfinder lore interpretation. How is it handled, according to lore?

Comment: I would bet the only answer anyone will ever get from Paizo is "Please to not be destroying the Prime Material Plane; we don't have extras."

Comment: 404 - plane not found: abort, retry, ignore?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton If you see this message, *always* choose retry.

Comment: @PaulZ don't be silly, of course they have spares! They have call it the *Prime* Material Plane to distinguish it from the backups, the Secondary Material Plane, Tertiary Material Plane, etc...

Comment: Is there more than one Prime in PF cosmology? Because in D&D there is only one.

Comment: oops, I accidentally the Material Plane

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this has never happened in-setting or in a canon source, so no-one knows the answer.

Even going outside of Pathfinder's canon and looking at D&D's long history of planar adventures, demiplanes have collapsed, outer planes have drifted away from the great wheel, inner planes have run aground on Prime worlds, but the Prime as a whole has endured.

Any answer to this question is therefore speculation—and therefore up to the whimsy of whatever GM sits at the head of the table when it happens.

Besides, I suspect a big part of the answer would depend on how the Prime was destroyed, and whether it was actually gone entirely from the cosmology or just had its contents smashed into little pieces/undergone heat death/collapsed into a supermassive Sphere of Annihilation.

Comment: It'd be awesome if you gave canon examples or sources for the events in the second paragraph.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Most of them are from the end of the adventure "Die, Vecna, Die!" in which the titular power managed to upset the multiverse before being defeated. Unfortunately, there was never any detail published that described which inner plane ran aground on which prime world, which outer plane drifted away, and what the consequences were, so there's not much of use that I could add - except that it's a popular fan theory that it explains the differences in the cosmology between 2e and 3e. Given that it's D&D lore and not PF lore, it wouldn't be that useful anyway.